# Configuring message limit in openfire

Tags: openfire

I understand that the **default size** for the message is 1MB.

Is there a way to re-configure the limit.

Any help on this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the "xmpp.parser.buffer.size" property in Openfire (in byte) .
The default value is indeed 1MB.

(GIT code):

```
private static final String MAX_PROPERTY_NAME = "xmpp.parser.buffer.size";
maxBufferSize = JiveGlobals.getIntProperty(MAX_PROPERTY_NAME, 1048576);
```